# PermissionError: [WinError 5] when running script

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I'm getting the error that is commented out at the bottom of the code snippet.
I'm runnning all of this in IDLE. I'm on windows and have tried right click run as admin on IDLE thinking that could help but it isn't working. I previously ran code like this to accomplish the same task but on different folders. I also know that there are other easier ways to move files but since I'm following the exercises in a book, I'd like to accomplish the end goal of moving several files into a different directory in a way that is as close as possible to what I have described below. Specifically I'm looking for input on what is causing this error and understanding why.

I came across [this](https://youtu.be/5WLV87B63SY) video, ff to [7:40]. The context is a little bit different but the error message is the same. Even so I can't see how the explanation relates to what I'm doing, and specifically in my python context. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import pathlib
import shutil

home = pathlib.Path.home()
pictures = home / "Pictures"
imgfiles = pictures / "imgfiles"
file1 = pictures / "image1.png"
file2 = pictures / "image2.gif"
file3 = pictures / "Uplay" / "image3.png"
file4 = pictures / "camera roll" / "image4.jpg"
filelist = [file1, file2, file3, file4]
sourcefiles = []
destination = imgfiles

for file in filelist:
    file.touch()

for file in pictures.rglob("image?.???"):
    sourcefiles.append(file)

for path in sourcefiles:
    path.replace(destination)
```

The traceback looks as follows:

```
Obtain the following Error when running the last line of code: PermissionError: [WinError 5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#42>", line 2, in <module>
   path.replace(destination)
 File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 1366, in replace
   self._accessor.replace(self, target)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acesso negado: 'C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Pictures\\image1.png' -> 'C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Pictures\\imgfiles'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to write a file as a directory and Windows does not like that. If you replace your destination with the destination file name it would work just fine.

So if I were to re-write your code, I would do it as below:-

```
import pathlib
import shutil

home = pathlib.Path.home()
pictures = home / "Pictures"
imgfiles = pictures / "imgfiles"
file1 = pictures / "image1.png"
file2 = pictures / "image2.gif"
file3 = pictures / "Uplay" / "image3.png"
file4 = pictures / "camera roll" / "image4.jpg"
filelist = [file1, file2, file3, file4]
sourcefiles = []
destination = imgfiles

for file in filelist:
    file.touch()

for file in pictures.rglob("image?.???"):
    destination=imgfiles/ str(file)[str(file).rfind("\\")+1:]  #Added
    file.replace(destination)

#Commented
#for path in sourcefiles: 
#    path.replace(destination)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Sherin, thank you for getting back to me with that much appreciated. In the mean time someone else came back with an answer to this question on a different platform. I'll post it here in case someone else needs it.  The last line of code should be replaced by the following:  path.replace(destination / path.name)

Comment: @TiagoMendes: Which is exactly what I did as well, instead of using `path.name`, I used   `str(file)[str(file).rfind("\\")+1:] `. I am sure you would have seen that the variable `destination` and `imgfiles` contains the same value.

Comment: Hi Sherin, you are right. I wasn't understanding the logic behind all of this, but after trying a few things out his answer made sense and so does yours.

Comment: Happy to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
for path in sourcefiles:
    path.replace(destination)
```

with:

```
for path in sourcefiles:
    path.replace(destination / path.name)
```

Kudos to Bart from RealPython for the answer.